# Mago gives D0006: Error: Type resolve failed when debugging with VisualD

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, d, visual-d

I'm trying to debug this very simple piece of code.

```
import std.stdio;

class Test
{
    int i = 5;
}

int main(string[] argv)
{
    Test test = new Test;

    return 0;
}
```

However, Mago gives me error `D0006: Error: Type resolve failed` when I'm trying to inspect object `test`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Moving project to a path without spaces, creating a brand new project
2. Moving D compiler to a path without spaces, reinstalling many times
3. Moving VisualD to a path without spaces, reinstalling many times

I'm using DMD version 2.066.1, VisualD version 0.3.40 and Visual Studio 2013 (Professional).

How can I solve this problem?

Screenshot of the error: [image: Image of debugging window showing the error]